# Eyewitness testimony study from Power of Habit

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory, reference-request, habituation

In his book *The Power of Habit*, Charles Duhigg refers to some study from the University of Western Ontario:

> STEP THREE: ISOLATE THE CUE
>
> About a decade ago, a psychologist at the University of Western Ontario tried to answer a question that had bewildered social scientists for years: Why do some eyewitnesses of crimes misremember what they see, while other recall events accurately? (...)
>
> She wondered if researchers were making a mistake by
> focusing on what questioners and witnesses had said, rather than how
> they were saying it. She suspected there were subtle cues that were
> influencing the questioning process. But when she watched videotape
> after videotape of witness interviews, looking for these cues, she
> couldn’t see anything. There was so much activity in each interview –
> all the facial expressions, the different ways the questions were
> posed, the fluctuating emotions – that she couldn’t detect any
> patterns.
>
> So she came up with an idea: She made a list of a few elements she
> would focus on – the questioners’ tone, the facial expressions of the
> witness, and how close the witness and the questioner were sitting to
> each other. Then, she removed any information that would distract her
> from those elements. She turned down the volume on the television so,
> instead of hearing words, all she could detect was the tone of the
> questioner’s voice. She taped a sheet of paper over the questioner’s
> face, so all she could see was the witnesses’ expressions. She held a
> tape measure to the screen to measure their distance from each other.
>
> And once she started studying these specific elements, patterns leapt
> out. She saw that witnesses who misremembered facts usually were
> questioned by cops who used a gentle, friendly tone. When witnesses
> smiled more, or sat closer to the person asking the questions, they
> were more likely to misremember.
>
> In other words, when environmental cues said “we are friends” – a
> gentle tone, a smiling face – the witnesses were more likely to
> misremember what had occurred. Perhaps it was because, subconsciously,
> those friendship cues triggered a habit to please the questioner.
>
> But the importance of this experiment is that those same tapes had
> been watched by dozens of other researchers. Lots of smart people had
> seen the same patterns, but no one had recognized them before. Because
> there was too much information in each tape to see a subtle cue.
>
> Once the psychologist decided to focus on only three categories of
> behavior, however, and eliminate the extraneous information, the
> patterns leapt out.

Whole chapter is available here [How Habits Work](http://charlesduhigg.com/how-habits-work/).

Do you know guys where I can find this study? In it not listed in notes.

Comment: I've read the book section in question in the meantime. Alas the main point there was not a published study but the psychologist's observation about her own behavior. That would be considered [anecdotal evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anecdotal_evidence) so usually not publishable, except maybe in a book or commentary. The actual study she was doing might have been published, but I doubt it will say much about the main point in that book section.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll write an email to author of the book and I'll ask him directly whether study exists.